# Python io.StringIO adding extra newline at the end

Tags: python

It appears that Python's `io.StringIO` adds an extra newline at the end when I'm calling its `getvalue` method.

For the following code:

```py
import io
s = io.StringIO()
s.write("1\n2\n3\n4\n5\n")
res = s.getvalue()
s.close()
print(res)
```

What I'm getting is this, with an extra newline in the end:

```
1
2
3
4
5
```

I checked the output with a hex editor, and I'm sure there's an extra newline.

The [document](https://docs.python.org/3/library/io.html#io.StringIO) says that:

> The newline argument works like that of TextIOWrapper. The default is to consider only \n characters as ends of lines and to **do no newline translation**. If newline is set to None, newlines are written as \n on all platforms, but universal newline decoding is still performed when reading.

And I don't recall the `write` method append newlines per call.

So why is it adding newlines? I'm writing a script so I would like to make sure that it's behavior is consistent.

Comment: try `print(repr(res))`

Comment: ...you explicitly write `\n` as last character an then `print(...)` (which adds a newline of its own).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

StringIO isn't doing this, it's `print`.

`print` prints all its arguments, seperated by `sep` (by default a space), and ending with `end`, by default a newline. You can suppress that by doing:

```
print(res, end="")
```

Comment: Happens to everyone once in a while :)